# What is the best approach to monitor telemetry events from Spring Boot application which runs in a minikube cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, minikube, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am looking for a way to monitor metrics from my Spring Boot application which runs in a minikube cluster to in an Azure portal.
So far for the demo I have built a telemetry as follows and connected my application to Application Insights in Azure:

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
MetricTelemetry telemetry = new MetricTelemetry();
telemetry.setTimestamp(timestamp);
telemetry.setName("changed records");
telemetry.setValue(10);
telemetryClient.trackMetric(telemetry);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgzFl.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, this works fine. But now I need a way to filter by the namespace and pod. For example, in my student work I have 3 different namespaces with 2 pods each.

Does anyone know a good way to get the namespace and pod information from my minikube cluster?

Comment: If MetricTelemetry works as Prometheus metrics, (supporting labels). I would consider passing a namespace and pod details into the pod using ENVs. Later using 'em as metrics labels.

Answer (score 0):

Pod fields such as namespace, node name, pod name and IP etc can be pass to your container via environment variables at runtime, checkout the example from the official document [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables).